# Cannot bind to TCP port 443 because it is in use by another process Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: hyper-v, system-center

i created a Template with my Virtual Machine Manager. ( SystemCenter 2012 SP1 ) I am trying to deploy this to my hyper-v host. After a wihle , the process is going to stop with an error:

> Error (22042) The service (123) was not successfully deployed. Review
>   the event log to determine the cause before you take corrective
>   action.
>
> Recommended Action The deployment can be restarted by retrying the
>   job.
>
> Error (12702) Cannot bind to TCP port 443 because it is in use by
>   another process on the vmmanger.de.myserver.corp server.
>
> Recommended Action Wait until the other process is completed, and then
>   try the operation again.
>
> Error (12702) Cannot bind to TCP port 443 because it is in use by
>   another process on the vmmanger.de.myserver.corp server.
>
> Recommended Action Wait until the other process is completed, and then
>   try the operation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any other network applications running? You can check this with `netstat` on the command prompt. Port 443 is the default port for HTTPS servers, do you have one running on your computer? When you've found the process with `netstat`, end it and try this again - it should work afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

port `443` is bound for `https` web communications.